# Is there a way to request admin rights on button click in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

My electron app for windows needs to have administrator rights to delete files with fs and fs-extra.

But it only needs it on pressing a button so i don't want to request admin rights when the app starts.

Is there a way to request admin rights on button click?

Comment: What OS are you talking about? Requesting privileges is very different for different OS. But all have in common, that you cannot elevate an already running process, but you just can restart (or start an additional instance of) that process, with elevated permissions.

Comment: It's for windows